# Is there a way to get rid of the row before and after a certain string in R(based on imported data from excel)?

Tags: r

So I have to get rid of the one row before and after a certain keyword in found in the large dataset and I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I know that there is an adjacent function that I can take advantage of to do this but it isn't doing what it needs to do so Im definitely doing something wrong. Is there anyone who can help me use the adjacent function or a different function to achieve this please and thank you!

Comment: What is the `adjacent function` you are using? Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: I think it is along the lines of this function adjacency(x, fromCells, toCells, directions) but I dont know how to cater this function to specifically delete the rows above and below the keyword especially since there are multiple cells that has the keyword

Comment: this is the only way that I thought there could be but if anyone has any other methods please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Sample Data
x <- data.frame(row = 1:5, string = LETTERS[1:5])
#  row string
#1   1      A
#2   2      B
#3   3      C
#4   4      D
#5   5      E

matchingRow <- match("C", x$string)
x[-c(matchingRow-1, matchingRow+1),] #romove row befor and after matichingRow
#  row string
#1   1      A
#3   3      C
#5   5      E
```